# Python Find & Count Certain Word within (Strings) List Items

Tags: python, list, search, count, cpu-word

Hello dear Programmers,

I want to find certain words within List Items. My Input looks like this:

```
myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen'...]
```

I want to find and count \tNN\t or \tADJ\t or \tVFIN\t.
The position of the words that I want to count is always the same, like you can see in the example.

I tried the following code, but I get the following error: ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 3)

```
from collections import Counter

myInputList = Counter([b for a,b,c in myInputList])
    print(myInputList)
```

Actually, I can see why this code is not working. But I don't have another approach.

So my goal is to count the Part of Speach tags that are between the \t.
So at the end I want to say: There are 5 NN, 4 ADJA...

Comment: `split` the strings on `\t`.  `Counter(s.split('\t')[1] for s in myInputList)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the case when '\t' not present

```
from collections import Counter
myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen','xyz']
Counter([x.split('\t')[1] for x in myInputList if '\t' in x])
```

Convert into Dictionary

```
from collections import Counter
myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen','xyz']
d=dict(Counter([x.split('\t')[1] for x in myInputList if '\t' in x]))
print(d['NN'])
```

**Output:1**

Comment: Thank you! This works! :-) And one additional Question: Now I would like to count only the NN, and to have as output just the number, nothing else. like: 1

Comment: Counter has the structure similar to that of the dictionary. Updated my code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
a, b, c = ('\tNN\t', '\tADJ\t', '\tVFIN\t')

myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen']

print(len([i for i in myInputList if any(j in i for j in [a, b, c])]))
#3
```

Comment: Thank you. Your Code is working. But I tried to modify it a little bit, to get for example only NN to count. Can you see why where my mistake is? I did it like this:                                                                                                                        a = ('\tNN\t')
myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen']
print(len([i for i in myInputList if (j in i for j in a)]))
# I get 3 as result                                                                                                   # but I should get 1 as result

Comment: @AnnaLise As I suggested in edit use `print(len([i for i in myInputList if any(j in i for j in [a])]))` because `... for j in a` splits a into `['\t', 'N', 'N', '\t']`

Answer (score 0):

```
myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen']

newList = []
for i in myInputList:

    newList.extend(i.split("\t"))

from collections import Counter
Counter(newList)
```

gives

```
{'ADJ': 1,
 'Haus': 1,
 'Hauses': 1,
 'NN': 1,
 'VFIN': 1,
 'gehen': 1,
 'geht': 1,
 'gut': 1,
 'guten': 1}
```

If you want and you're sure that you want only the elements in the 2ND index, then you can simply do

```
myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen']

newList = []
for i in myInputList:

    newList.append(i.split("\t"))

from collections import Counter



onlySecond = [i[1] for i in newList]
dict(Counter(onlySecond))
```

will give you

```
{'ADJ': 1, 'NN': 1, 'VFIN': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). If there is a possibility of more than one value occurring in a list item, then you can remove `break`, which otherwise stops at the first match for a particular string.

```
myInputList = ['Hauses\tNN\tHaus', 'guten\tADJ\tgut', 'geht\tVFIN\tgehen']
values = ['\tNN\t', '\tADJ\t', '\tVFIN\t']

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for item in myInputList:
    for v in values:
        if v in item:
            d[v] += 1
            break

print(d)

defaultdict(int, {'\tADJ\t': 1, '\tNN\t': 1, '\tVFIN\t': 1})
```